# Why is the eps generated by adobe illustrator far less clear than that generated by Inkscape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape

I used Adobe Illustrator to draw the picture. I save it in `eps` format. But when I insert it into a LaTeX file and generate a PDF, the picture is very unclear.

But when I save the picture as `svg` format, then use Inkscape to open, and then generate `eps` format, insert it into a LaTeX file and generate a PDF file, the picture is very clear.

Why is it? How can I set up Adobe Illustrator to make the picture clearer?

This picture is generated by Inkscape:

[image]

This is an image generated by Adobe Illustrator:

[image]

Comment: Eps is a fairly complex format. Hard to day without analyzing your files, which i wouldnt do for you even if you paid me. But looks to me that your font embedding is failing to work. Also not sure how i could deduce anything of unclarity related from your image. PS: the position of your images depend on screen size so try to refrain from using left and right, its confusing if the images are on top of eachother.

Comment: I'd **guess** it has something to do with Inkscape being XML (svg) at it's core whereas Illustrator is postscript. Latex may be more adept at handling XML.

Comment: @Scott makes no sense eps is postscript no matter what you use.

Comment: The image from Illustrator seems stretched vertically and it's smaller than the one from Inkscape. If you are to really compare them, please put some effort into exporting them at the exact same size. (And yes, the font is missing in Illustrator.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I just selected and replaced all fonts. It seemed to become clear after that. But what confuses me is why the arrow also seems to be clear?

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced the font inside. Replace the font with Arial, and then insert the image into the pdf file generated by Latex. After that the picture became clearer.